# maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get following error:

> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

I can see in other threads it has something to do with you need to add a go. I am not sure how to do this, and notice its a recursive procedure. Any ideas how to solve this?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetMigrate]
    (@DirId uniqueidentifier,
     @Source nvarchar(255),
     @Recursive bit)
AS
    DECLARE @IsRoot AS BIT

    SELECT @IsRoot = IsMigrationRoot 
    FROM directories 
    WHERE folderid = @DirId

    IF (@IsRoot = 1)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 
    END

    UPDATE directories  
    SET migrate = 1, [source] = @Source 
    WHERE folderid = @DirId

    IF (@Recursive = 0)
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END

    DECLARE @parentid uniqueidentifier, @directoryid uniqueidentifier

    DECLARE Directories cursor local read_only for 
         SELECT FolderID, ParentFolderID 
         FROM directories 
         WHERE ParentFolderID = @DirId

    OPEN Directories

    FETCH NEXT FROM Directories INTO @directoryid, @parentid

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        --print @Path
        EXEC SetMigrate @directoryid, @Source, @Recursive

        FETCH NEXT FROM Directories INTO @directoryid, @parentid
    END

    CLOSE Directories
    DEALLOCATE Directories
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the begin and end for your if statement first. Also make sure that you have altered your database to allow for recursive_triggers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works for some executions so the database must allow it (its an azure sql server). I tried removing the begin and end from the if but still same result.

Comment: It seems like you can't go deeper than 32. a server restriction apparently. So you need to rewrite it some how using loops and stuff